# Shopify Custom App Admin REST API for Inventory_level/Set.Json Not Working getting Error(400) Bad Request

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Am trying to perform an Admin API POST using CURL to set inventory level via a Custom App, per [https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/**2023-04**/resources/inventorylevel#post-inventory-levels-set](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-04/resources/inventorylevel#post-inventory-levels-set) instruction.

The `item_inventory_id` and `location_id` have been verified to be correct, since I've been able to successfully perform GET methods for `inventory_level`, but for POST am getting `400 Bad Request Error`.  I'm at a loss as to why.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request | No JSON Error message returned

curl -X POST -v -u myAPIkey:mySecretKey -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: myAccessToken"  -d '{"location_id":85585101078,"inventory_item_id":47065562448150,"available":46}' https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/inventory_levels/set.json
```

**Swapping  position `inventory_item_id` to be listed first in JSON payload didn't help:**

```
curl -X POST -v -u myAPIkey:mySecretKey -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: myAccessToken"  -d '{"inventory_item_id":47065562448150,"location_id":85585101078,"available":46}' https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/inventory_levels/set.json
```

**Changing the content type to `application/x-ndjson` alters the response a bit, got a bit more detail in the returned JSON payload, but doesn't really make sense...**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request | {"errors":{"inventory_item_id":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}


curl -X POST -v -u myAPIkey:mySecretKey -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson; charset=utf-8" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: myAccessToken"  -d '{"location_id":85585101078,"inventory_item_id":47065562448150,"available":46}' https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/inventory_levels/set.json
```

**Swapping  position `inventory_item_id` with `ndjson` to be listed first in JSON payload also didn't help:**

```
curl -X POST -v -u myAPIkey:mySecretKey -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson; charset=utf-8" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: myAccessToken"  -d '{"inventory_item_id":47065562448150,"location_id":85585101078,"available":46}' https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/inventory_levels/set.json
```

**Here are the proofs that the `inventory_item_id` & `location_id` are accurate via successful GET methods:**

```
curl -X GET -v -u myAPIkey:mySecretKey -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: myAccessToken" https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/inventory_levels.json?inventory_item_ids=47065562448...
{"inventory_levels":[{"inventory_item_id":47065562448150,"location_id":85585101078,"available":999999,"updated_at":"2023-06-22T15:41:35-05:00","admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/InventoryLevel\/122010075414?inventory_item_id=47065562448150"}]}
```

**In addition, I've also confirmed that the item is being tracked**

```
curl -X GET -v -u myAPIkey:mySecretKey -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: myAccessToken" https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/inventory_items.json?ids=47065562448150
{"inventory_items":[{"id":47065562448150,"sku":"735X453","created_at":"2023-06-16T09:15:53-05:00","updated_at":"2023-06-22T15:41:30-05:00","requires_shipping":true,"cost":null,"country_code_of_origin":null,"province_code_of_origin":null,"harmonized_system_code":null,"tracked":true,"country_harmonized_system_codes":[],"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/InventoryItem\/47065562448150"}]}
```

**I believe I also have configured the Custom App with the appropriate permissions to write to `inventory_levels`:**

```
read_fulfillments, **write_inventory, read_inventory**, write_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders, read_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders, write_order_edits, read_order_edits, write_orders, read_orders, write_payment_customizations, read_payment_customizations, write_payment_terms, read_payment_terms, write_price_rules, read_price_rules, write_product_feeds, read_product_feeds, write_product_listings, read_product_listings, write_products, read_products, write_reports, read_reports, write_returns, read_returns, write_third_party_fulfillment_orders, read_third_party_fulfillment_orders, write_fulfillment_constraint_rules, read_fulfillment_constraint_rules
```

I'm also running into the same issue when attempting perform an update on `order.tags`.

**SUCCESS**

```
curl -X GET -v -u myAPIkey:myAPIsecret -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: myAccessToken" https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/orders/5384975778070.json?
```

**BUT A "PUT" API Call FAILED: BAD REQUEST**

```
curl -X PUT -v -u myAPIkey:myAPIsecret -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: myAccessToken" -d '{"order":{"id":5384975778070,"tags":"exported"}}' https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/orders/5384975778070.json
```

So far Shopify Support claims that it's out of their support scope and unfortunately, Shopify Community hasn't been of any help.

Expecting a 200 response and JSON payload confirming that the update was successful.  It might look something like this.

```
'{"inventory_item_id":47065562448150,"location_id":,"available":46}' https://test123.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/inventory_levels/set.json

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
  "inventory_level": {
    "inventory_item_id": 47065562448150,
    "location_id": 85585101078,
    "available": 46,
    "updated_at": "2023-06-14T15:00:18-04:00",
    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/InventoryLevel/655441491?inventory_item_id=47065562448150"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out it was because I was referencing `InventoryLevel` once I removed that, it worked. This is working:

```
curl -d '{"location_id":1234,"inventory_item_id":"1234","available":42}' \
-X POST "https://STORE.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/inventory_levels/set.json" \
-H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: TOKEN" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```